# How can I use pull up and pull down resistors in an H-bridge?

Tags: h-bridge, electrical, pullup, pulldown, electro-mechanical

I have to build an H bridge out of the following components

- 2 PNP transistors
- 2 NPN transistors
- battery 9V
- 4 resistors for the transistors
- a DC motor

I connected the above equipment but, I also have 2 resistors 10k ohm each. I don't know where to put then  because I don't know what they would do in an H-bridge.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Schematics is the language of electronic engineers and worth more than a thousand words. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, you can draw one using the built-in tool.

Comment: @JRE You beat me by 18 seconds...

Comment: Were you given those parts and told that you can build an H-bridge from them, or did you collect them yourself?  Is this from a kit or is it a classroom assignment?

Comment: @winny:  I seem to be turning into a grammar nazi.  Posts with poor grammar, capitalization, and formatting drive me up the wall.

Comment: Heil @JRE (kidding).

Comment: @JRE              yes it is from a kit, I can do the h bridge but the thing is where to fit these 2 resistors in it

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Surely the kit came with a circuit diagram? [Edit] to post a photo of what you've got, make and part number for the kit and a link to the datasheet or supplier.

Comment: There seem to be a bunch of diodes missing from that kit too, unless it's purpose is to blow up transistors. Any H bridge motor driver circuit should tell you what to do with them.

Comment: If it's a kit, can you link to a description of it?

Comment: @JRE sorry I meant an assignment that was meant to be prepared from some kit.